# Соединение с внешней БД из Docker-контейнера

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, docker, виртуализация

Создание БД postgreSQL внутри Docker-образа подробно описано в [документации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/)

Но как быть, когда БД располагается на production-сервере? Как присоединить внешнюю БД при запуске контейнера?

Как понимаю, при сборке образа ее нельзя включить в Dockerfile, так как используется она только на production-сервере.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, о взаимодействии БД и контейнерах. В моем понимании должно существовать две базы - тестовая (для разработчиков, тестеров) и боевая (исользуется на основном сайте).

Можно такую схему использовать с Docker-контейнерами?

Comment: а вы к БД по сети обращаетесь?

Comment: необязательно по сети, допустим я запустил контейнер на продакш сервере, где располагается база

Comment: и вы на прямую обращаетесь к файлам БД? или через TCP?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я работаю с Django, в production-файле я указываю параметры подключения к БД: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432', а методы, с которыми я работаю (типа .get_object(id=2)), фреймворк  уже  транслирует в SQL. получается напрямую

Comment: вот вместо localhost пропишите какое-нибудь имя и используйте один из способов из ответа.

Comment: да вообще никакой разницы с обычным запуском нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если к БД вы обращаетесь по сети, то все, что вам нужно - это передать в контейнер адрес базы данных. Это можно сделать множеством способов:

1. Прописываете dns имя в настройках приложения и при старте контейнера добавляете IP прямо в hosts файл `--add-host <dns имя>:<IP>`
2. Приложение берет адрес БД из переменной окружения (назовем ее DB_ADDRESS) - при старте контейнера устанавливаете эту переменную `-e "DB_ADDRESS=<IP или dns имя>"`
3. Приложение берет адрес БД из какой-нибудь системы конфигурации - Consul, Etcd, ZooKeeper, etc
4. Приложение получает адрес БД в качестве параметра при старте - при старте контейнера передаете его в виде последнего аргумента у `docker run`

Comment: вы меня снова выручаете) а что насчет вопроса разделения БД? такое практикуется?

Comment: Разделения на production и для разработчиков? Да. Обычно баз несколько. Разработчики могут запускать базы у себя на машинах (в контейнерах) или использовать какую-то общую, но не production.

Comment: оке, изначально база где находится? в образе с проектом или с ней создают отдельный образ как в доках https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/ ?

Comment: Я создаю отдельный контейнер с базой. При создании контейнера при помощи "sql" (в кавычках, так как sql генерируется) создаю нужные таблицы и пр.

Answer (score 1):

Обнаружение сервисов не такая тривиальная проблема как может показаться. Передавать адрес БД через переменные или с помощью линковки не решает эту проблему. Лишь откладывает. Перезапуск контейнера с БД потребует перезапуск все связанных с ней сервисов.
Подобные задачи очень изящно решаются с помощью DNS. Например с помощью [Consul](http://consul.io). Сервис регистрируется с помощью REST API:

```
curl -d '{"ID": "db1","Name": "db1","Tags": ["master"],"Address": "172.17.0.1","Port": 5432}' http://CONSUL_AGENT_IP:8500/v1/agent/service/register
```

Доступ к сервису производится по доменному имени. Например, для домена domain.tld:

```
$ ping db1.domain.tld
PING db1.domain.tld (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=61 time=33.941 ms
```

---

Если решите использовать Consul: Статья [Service Discovery с помощью Consul](https://www.influunt.ru/service-discovery-with-consul) поможет разобраться с запуском кластера и регистрацией сервисов.